# How to return nested tables (one-to-many) in .NET Core WebAPI using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am new to .NET and having trouble figuring out why Im getting certain results.  I found some results on eager vs lazy loading but none of the solutions have worked.

> I have changed the names of columns and data because its work related, so no public repo is available.

Currently my frontend is receiving data shaped as so:

```
{
    id: 234,
    column1: 1,
    column2: 2,
    column3: null
}
```

I want it to return one-to-many relationships in a nestest array like so:

```
{
    id: 234,
    column1: 1,
    column2: 2,
    column3: [
        {
            table2Column1: 1,
            table2Column2: 2,
            table2Column3: 3,
        },
        {
            table2Column1: 7,
            table2Column2: 8,
            table2Column3: 9,
        },
    ]
}
```

Below are my Models and Controller Patterns:

```
// Table1.cs

...
public int Id { get; set; }
public int Column1 { get; set; }
public int Column2 { get; set; }
public ICollection<Table2> Column3 { get; set; }
...
```

---

```
// Table2.cs
...
public int Id { get; set; }
public int Table2Column1 { get; set; }
public int Table2Column2 { get; set; }
public int Table2Column3 { get; set; }

public int Table1Id { get; set; }
public Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
...
```

---

```
//Table1Controller.cs
...
// GET: api/table1/{id}
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public Task<ActionResult<Table1>> GeTable1ById(int id)
{
    return await _context.Table1.FindAsync(id);
}
...
```

I found information saying an Include statement must be used to force eager loading so I changed the controller to be:

```
//Table1Controller.cs
...
// GET: api/table1/{id}
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<Table1> GeTable1ById(int id)
{
    return _context.Table1
                      .Include("Table2")
                      .Where(p => p.Id == id);
}
...
```

Ive tried a few variations but the gist of the error is that I have changed the shape of the data, so it doesnt fit the model... though it should because it should be anticipating an ICollection from the linked table.  EFCore is fine with it when creating the migration and updating the data, because everything is correct in SQLServer with Foriegn Keys.

The error returned is: `error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert the type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Project.Models.Table1>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<Project.Models.Table1>'`

How do I eagerly load and join tables into a complete record?
Thanks for the help.

---

---

RESOLVED

Original answer by Sergey worked but failed on front end for circular reference (which is required by EFCore). So you have to tell the Json Serializer to ignore the backwards reference.  Working code below:

// Table2.cs
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serializer;
...
public int Id { get; set; }
public int Table2Column1 { get; set; }
public int Table2Column2 { get; set; }
public int Table2Column3 { get; set; }

```
public int Table1Id { get; set; }
[JsonIgnore]
public Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
...
```

---

```
//Table1Controller.cs
...
// GET: api/table1/{id}
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<Table1> GeTable1ById(int id)
{
    return _context.Table1
                      .Include("Table2")
                      .Where(p => p.Id == id)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your action to this:

```
HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<Table1> GeTable1ById(int id)
{
  
return _context.Table1
                      .Include(t=>t.Column3)
                      .Where(p => p.Id == id)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This let me build, but a call to the API now triggers an Error

`System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This is either due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum depth of 32`  Is this because my Table2 has a reference back to Table1?  EFCore docs said that was necessary.

Comment: Got the answer,  your original answer worked, then to avoid the circular reference you have to update Table2 with a `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on the backwards reference.  Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Thanks for a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including table name, you have to Include navigation property. This query should work:

```
var query =  _context.Table1
                .Include(t1 => t1.Column3)
                .Where(p => p.Id == id);
```

Comment: This does not change the error. I dont think the problem is getting the data returned from the query, I think it has something to do with the shape of the data and expected type return